# create python code to figure out start velocity

Tags: python, physics

Have a task and need to figure out the start velocity of an iron ball shot vertically upwards. We know this [information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxDpc.png).

Comment: Please read [ask]. What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? And please do not include information as a picture, add it to the body of the question.

Comment: @Lomtrur Havent really tried anything, I dont know any python and my teacher expects us to know this. I hasnt even tried to learn us anything

Comment: Complain to your techer or to your techer's boss then.

Comment: @Daviid Should definitely do that

Comment: @lukashb: Do you know the math to perform the calculation(s) that you need?  Are you able to figure out the result on paper without using Python (or any other programming language)?  If not then the problem has nothing to do with Python.  But if so, then if the problem is simply that you don't know how to use Python then the solution to that problem is to use your favorite search engine to find introductory tutorials on Python.

Comment: @David Thank you! Yes i know how to do the calculations on paper, just dont know any python. Should probably learn some, instead of looking for cheap solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values from your image are as follows:

- mass sphere: 263.8602726 kg
- drag coefficient: 0.47
- air density: 1.225 kg/m³
- max height: 80 m
- acceleration due to gravity (G): 9.805 m/s²

---

Assuming you can neglect air resistance, you could use the kinematic equation:

```
v^2 + u^2 = 2as
```

where:

- v is the final velocity (0 m/s at the maximum height).
- u is the start velocity.
- a is the acceleration (in this case, -9.805 m/s² due to gravity).
- s is the displacement (80 m).

We can rearrange the equation to solve for the start velocity u:

```
u = sqrt(v^2 -2as)
```

Implementing this in Python is relatively straightforward:

```
def calculate_start_velocity(displacement: float,
                             acceleration: float) -> float:
  """Calculate the start velocity for an object given its displacement and acceleration.

  Args:
      displacement: The displacement of the object (maximum height reached).
      acceleration: The acceleration (should be negative for gravity).

  Returns:
      float: The calculated start velocity.
  """
  final_velocity_squared = 0  # Since final velocity at max height is 0.
  start_velocity_squared = final_velocity_squared - 2 * acceleration * displacement
  start_velocity = start_velocity_squared**0.5
  return start_velocity


def main() -> None:
  """Main function to calculate and print the start velocity."""
  max_height = 80.0  # Displacement.
  gravity = -9.805  # Acceleration due to gravity.
  start_velocity = calculate_start_velocity(max_height, gravity)
  print(f'Initial velocity of the sphere: {start_velocity:.2f} m/s')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**Output:**

```
Initial velocity of the sphere: 39.61 m/s
```

---

Assuming that air resistance is supposed to be taken into account you can use [`scipy.optimze.newton`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html) (which uses the [secant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) when the derivative of the function is not provided):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton


def find_initial_velocity(v0, mass, drag_coefficient, air_density, diameter, g,
                          max_height):
  """
  Compute the difference between the calculated max height and actual 
  max height for a given initial velocity considering air resistance.
  """
  # Time step for numerical simulation
  dt = 0.01  # in seconds
  velocity = v0
  height = 0
  while velocity > 0:
    # Drag force
    area = np.pi * (diameter / 2)**2
    drag_force = 0.5 * drag_coefficient * air_density * area * velocity**2
    # Net acceleration (both gravity and drag slow down the sphere)
    acceleration = g + drag_force / mass
    # Update velocity and height
    velocity -= acceleration * dt
    height += velocity * dt
  return height - max_height


def main():
  """Calculate the initial velocity of a sphere shot upwards."""
  # Given constants
  mass = 263.8602726  # in kg
  density_of_iron = 7874  # in kg/m^3
  drag_coefficient = 0.47
  air_density = 1.225  # in kg/m^3
  max_height = 80  # in m
  g = 9.805  # in m/s^2
  # Calculate diameter of the sphere
  volume = mass / density_of_iron
  radius = (3 * volume / (4 * np.pi))**(1 / 3)
  diameter = 2 * radius
  # Initial guess for the initial velocity
  initial_guess = np.sqrt(2 * g * max_height)
  # Find the initial velocity using the Secant method
  initial_velocity = newton(find_initial_velocity,
                            initial_guess,
                            args=(mass, drag_coefficient, air_density,
                                  diameter, g, max_height))

  print(f'Initial velocity of the sphere: {initial_velocity:.2f} m/s')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**Output:**

```
Initial velocity of the sphere: 39.88 m/s
```

Comment: Since the mass (and so diameter from Iron density), drag coefficient and air density are supplied it is reasonable to assume that air resistance is supposed to be taken into account rather than just using a basic kinematic equation. This also makes sense because Python is supposed to be used and this would be appropriate for this more complex analysis. I could well see the Teacher rejecting this answer.

Comment: Diameter is needed for the air resistance and could be derived from the mass with an assumed density 7874 kg / m3 for Iron..

Comment: Updated, ptal  user19077881

Comment: At first glance an issue stands out: with air resistance the initial velocity must be greater to reach the same height since the drag force is always downwards.

Comment: Hint: gravity and air resistance are in the same direction - downwards.

Comment: Ah, both gravity and drag, slow down the sphere, i.e., `acceleration = g + drag_force / mass`... Great catch! Are/were you a physics major?